# Coverting Batch IP Addresses to Find Location

Tags: javascript, python, ip

Is there any service out there that will let me determine the location of 1000+ IP addresses? The services I've come across restrict it to 20, 40, 50, or 100 IP addresses. Is this something that can be programmed in Python? I have very minor experience in JavaScript/Python. Not sure if there's an API or service out there that will let me retrieve this information. I've heard of [GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/), but not sure where to get started.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use https://reallyfreegeoip.org/bulk online bulk ip location lookup tool. As far as I know, there is no limit. Just copy and paste your list. Might have to wait a while for it to go through your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free databases: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

APIs for those: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/#MaxMind_APIs

Use the Python API to write a script in Python, which queries the API for each IP address and then logs the results.

Comment: I'm trying to use the database method: http://geoip2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ but I can't seem to install `geoip[DB]` because I'm having difficulty with the installation instruction of libmaxminddb: https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb. I've tried both methods and Terminal states `./bootstrap` and `./configure` don't exist.

Comment: You have to follow every last step down to the letter. Also, check that you're in the right directory: use ls to see the current contents of the folder, and then cd into the proper directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this free online ip location bulk lookup tool. As far as I know, there is no limit. Just copy and paste your list. Might have to wait a while for it to go through your list.

https://reallyfreegeoip.org/bulk

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a [script](https://github.com/realpython/python-scripts/blob/master/25_ip2geolocation.py) to handle this.

Here is the source:

```
import csv
import requests


def get_addresses(filename):
    """
    Given a CSV file, this function returns a list of lists
    where each element (list) in the outer list contains the
    row info from the csv file.
    """
    all_addresses = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            all_addresses.append(row)
    return all_addresses


def get_geolocation(all_the_ip_address):
    """
    Given a list of lists from `get_addresses()`, this function
    returns an updated lists of lists containing the geolocation.
    """
    print("Getting geo information...")
    updated_addresses = []
    counter = 1
    # update header
    header_row = all_the_ip_address.pop(0)
    header_row.extend(['Country', 'City'])
    # get geolocation
    for line in all_the_ip_address:
        print "Grabbing geo info for row # {0}".format(counter)
        r = requests.get('https://reallyfreegeoip.org/json/{0}'.format(line[0]))
        line.extend([str(r.json()['country_name']), str(r.json()['city'])])
        updated_addresses.append(line)
        counter += 1
    updated_addresses.insert(0, header_row)
    return updated_addresses


def create_csv(updated_address_list):
    """
    Given the updated lists of lists from `get_geolocation()`, this function
    creates a new CSV.
    """
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(updated_address_list)
    print "All done!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_file = '25_sample_csv.csv'
    all_the_ip_address = get_addresses(csv_file)
    updated_address_list = get_geolocation(all_the_ip_address)
    create_csv(updated_address_list)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [blockfinder](https://github.com/ioerror/blockfinder) as it gets information from the IP registrars. Every GeoIP provider I've seen pretty much has the same data unless they're backed by a real data warehouse (More expensive than regular folks can afford, think: 'credit card company').

Yeah, granted the IP might not be in the exact province, but you can at least narrow it down by country which is probably sufficient for most folks.

Word of warning, last time I looked there was only the blockfinder command utility - I don't even know if they expose an API. But, it is written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [bulk IP address](http://blog.ipapi.co/2016/12/bulk-ip-checker.html) lookup tool from `ipapi.co` that you can use to convert a thousand or so IP addresses to location.

It's available via both web interface and as an API that can be called from Python / Javascript / PHP etc.